# How do I use grep to find words of specified or unspecified length?

Tags: unix, grep, pipe, cut

In the Unix command line (CentOS7) I have to use the `grep` command to find all words with:

1. At least *n* characters
2. At most *n* characters
3. Exactly *n* characters

I have searched the posts here for answers and came up with `grep -E '^.{8}' /sample/dir` but this only gets me the words with at least 8 characters.

Using the `$` at the end returns nothing. For example:
`grep -E '^.{8}$' /sample/dir`

I would also like to trim the info in /sample/dir so that I only see the specific information. I tried using a pipe:

```
cut -f1,7 -d: | grep -E '^.{8}' /sample/dir
```

Depending on the order, this only gets me one or the other, not both.

I only want the usernames at the beginning of each line, not all words in each line for the entire file.

For example, if I want to find userids on my system, these should be the results:

1.

```
tano-ahsoka
skywalker-a
kenobi-obiwan
```

2. 

```
ahsoka-t
luke-s
leia-s
```

3. 

```
ahsoka-t
kenobi-o
grievous
```

I'm looking for two responses here as I have already figured out number 1.

Numbers 2 and 3 are not working for some reason.

If possible, I'd also like to apply the cut for all three outputs.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your requirements conflict. Please elaborate further with examples and desired results.

Comment: @konsolebox I've added the example output as requested and clarified my question. I'm looking for two solutions; number 2 and number 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run one grep for extracting the words, and another for filtering based on length.

```
grep -oE '(\w|-)+' file | grep -Ee '^.{8,}$'
grep -oE '(\w|-)+' file | grep -Ee '^.{,8}$'
grep -oE '(\w|-)+' file | grep -Ee '^.{8}$'
```

Update the pattern based on requirements and maybe use `-r` and specify a directory instead of a file. Adding `-h` option may also be needed to prevent the filenames from being printed.

Comment: Thank you! The only change I needed to make was this:
`grep -oE '^(\w|-)+' file | ...`

Putting the `^` at the beginning of the expression gave me all the words at the beginning of each line instead of all words in all lines.

Comment: @sprklpixl there is no clue in your question that you want to ignore words that aren't at the start of lines, please fix your question as that makes it a simpler problem that can be solved with a simpler solution.

Comment: @EdMorton I have adjusted my post accordingly. My example was to retrieve usernames from /etc/passwd. I apologize if this was a poor example of what I was looking for. I was a bit rushed as I couldn't plug in my laptop and it was nearing death. I really appreciate your response, and I didn't mind having to make the adjustment. I posted the adjustment in case others needed to grab just the first word as well. I'm excited to be delving deeper into the Unix command line and what it can do. it's a very powerful tool, as your original response demonstrates :)

Comment: You may want to ask a new question as this is not how you'd go about retrieving user names from /etc/password, it's much simpler than this and wouldn't involve `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation of grep, it might work to use:

```
grep -o -E '\<\w{8}\>'     # exactly 8
grep -o -E '\<\w{8,}\>'    # 8 or more
grep -o -E '\<\w{,8}\>'    # 8 or less
```